# real infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $p>1$. Prove that $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {\sqrt[p] {n^{p-1}}}{(n+1)n} <\infty.$$

I got that the numerator is less than $n$ so that I want to find something that is lower than the denominator. Thus I could use the comparison theorem and see that converges. Am I on the right track?

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2793141/a-real-serie-convergent). Write the exponent as $(p - 1)/p - 2$ for the comparison.

Comment: Consider the asympthotic behaviour for $n$ large and then refer to limit comparison test.

Comment: @PattrickD Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that for $n$ large

$$ \frac {\sqrt[p] {n^{p-1}}}{(n+1)n}\sim \frac{1}{n^{2-\frac{p-1}p}}=\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac1p}}$$

with

$$\alpha=1+\frac1p>1$$

for $p>1$, then we can apply the limit comparison test with $\sum \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac1p}}$.

Comment: So that I can say that the second expression converges hence the first one does the same for the comparison theorem?

Comment: @PattrickD For n large the given series behaves as $\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac1p}}$ then it converges. To prove rigoursly that we can refer to limit comparison test between the original series and the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac1p}}$. Refer to http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The $n$th term equals

$$\frac{n^{1-1/p}}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n^{1/p}(n+1)} < \frac{1}{n^{1/p}n}=\frac{1}{n^{1+1/p}}.$$

Apply the comparison test.